# How to find who deleted records from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I checked and found a table's records deleted and executed below query to find who deleted few records:

```
SELECT
 [Current LSN],
 [Operation],
 [Transaction ID],
  [Description], SPID,[Begin Time], [Transaction SID],
  name 'LoginName'
 FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL),
   (select sid,name from sys.syslogins) sl
where [Transaction Name] LIKE '%delete%' and [Transaction SID] = sl.sid

  **even I tried this below:**


   DECLARE @TableName sysname
   SET @TableName = 'dbo.table1'
   SELECT
u.[name] AS UserName
, l.[Begin Time] AS TransactionStartTime
FROM
fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) l
 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
    [Transaction ID]
FROM 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE
    AllocUnitName LIKE @TableName + '%'
AND
    Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
) deletes
    ON  deletes.[Transaction ID] = l.[Transaction ID]
    INNER JOIN
    sysusers u
    ON  u.[sid] = l.[Transaction SID]
```

However, this is not returning any result. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any extra settings I needs to do in SQL Server 2008 to see the logs? Who has done what?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135080

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: @TryingBest go through the follow link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/

Comment: @userfloflo, I would suggest you to create a server side trace or enable SQL Audit to track down activity ? How to enable these tracking?